# Preserving the (non-alphabetical) order of data sets or groups when saving to .hdf5

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I have some raw data that I would like to store in .hdf5 file format together with the results I get from the analysis of the data. Before saving the data to disk I sort the different data sets in a way that is meaningful to me, using time. One example of this could be that the data sets are sorted like this: ['50us','100us','200us','5ns','20ns','500ns'] - I generally sort the data with increasing time.

The problem is that when saving the data to the .hdf5 data sets are sorted alphabetically. To confirm this, I made this minimal working example:

```
with h5py.File(destination_folder+'\debugging.hdf5', 'w') as f:
    alphabet_example = ['zz9999', 'zz8888','aaaa9999','ZZ9999']
    for name in alphabet_example:
        group_string = 'testing/'+ name
        f[group_string] = np.linspace(1,10,37)

    real_example = ['50us','100us','200us','5ns','20ns','500ns']
    data_for_example = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    for num, name in enumerate(real_example):
        group_string = 'real/'+ name
        f[group_string] = data_for_example[num]


    for names in f['testing/']:
        print(names)

    print('\n')

    for names in f['real/']:
        print(names)
        print(f['real/'+names].value)
```

I would save me so much developing and executing times if the data sets (and groups) could be stored in the order I save them. Otherwise I have to run a function sorting the data **every time** I load data from file - this goes for both analysis and plotting of the data. Right now I am using a list of the alphabeyt to preface each data set so they become 'a_50us', 'b_100us', 'c_200us' etc., but it is a bit embarrassing to use that kind of solution when you want to share the code and .hdf5 files with collaborators.

I use windows 7, python 3.5 and h5py 2.6.0 if it matters :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible with h5py. However, it is possible using [netCDF4](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) (comes with the Anaconda distribution if you have that). HDF5 and NetCDF4 files are interoperable, so the resulting file will be able to be read later with h5py.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I will look into netCDF4 :)